# Running a java applet in web application with tomcat 6 and the redirection from IIS 8.5

Tags: java, iis, applet, tomcat6

I try to run an application web java with applet in page jsp and tomcat  by using a redirection isapi_redirect to IIS web server,  but i have an error like this :

```
load: class com.ubs.swidULF.v3.client.appletintegration.UlfDefaultAppletLauncher.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ubs.swidULF.v3.client.appletintegration.UlfDefaultAppletLauncher.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ubs.swidULF.v3.client.appletintegration.UlfDefaultAppletLauncher.class
```

This is the html of the applet in jsp file present in tomcat :

```
<param name= "java_archive" value="ulc-base-client-3.jar,ulc-servlet-client-6.3.2.jar, UAI_AppletIntegrationClient-4.jar, ULF_3_LookAndFeelClientLib-Signed-3.1.0-RC1-SNAPSHOT.jar" />  
<param name= "java_codebase" value="<%= request.getContextPath() + "/lib/" %>" / >
```

For information the jar are presents in the folder tomcat6.0/webapps/myapplication/lib  and when i test the link : http://myserver:88/ULF_3_LookAndFeelClientLib-Signed-3.1.0-RC1-SNAPSHOT.jar  i can download the jar, i can download all the jar,

an the class com.ubs.swidULF.v3.client.appletintegration.UlfDefaultAppletLauncher.class , it present in the jar UAI_AppletIntegrationClient-4.jar,ULF_3_LookAndFeelClientLib-Signed-3.1.0-RC1-SNAPSHOT.jar

for the redirection from IIS to tomcat , i use the dll isapi_redirect.
the application works with apache2.2 and tomcat 6

Comment: This is the code of the applet  <param name="java_archive" value="ulc-base-client-3.jar,ulc-servlet-client-6.3.2.jar,UAI_AppletIntegrationClient-4.jar,ULF_3_LookAndFeelClientLib-Signed-3.1.0-RC1-SNAPSHOT.jar" /> 
   <param name="java_codebase" value="<%= request.getContextPath() + "/lib/" %>" />
   <param name="java_code" value="UlfDefaultAppletLauncher.class" />

Comment: you are aware almost all (if not all) have discontinued support for applets years ago?

Comment: don't add more information about the question in a comment, edit it in your question.